# Pyaudio Installation Problem on Windows Through CMD

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

I was trying to install **Pyaudio** on my Windows 10 through CMD, but it shows an error. I have also installed **Visual C++**.

ERROR CODE looks like this:

> "Command "c:\users\injamul\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Injamul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6v7a5ry0\pyaudio\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Injamul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-okz6dexk\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Injamul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6v7a5ry0\pyaudio\"